# Адаптивная верстка на spa React

Tags: html, вёрстка, reactjs

Как правильно организовать проект на React с адаптивными под разные размеры экрана блоками? 
Возможно как то реализовать чтобы js который написан под один размер экрана не подгружался  с другим?

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так, но правильным решением будет создание компонентов, адаптивных под разные размеры экрана средствами CSS. Если квалификации написать подобные не хватает, то могу [посоветовать](https://material-ui.com/) готовые.